# sorting/grouping a multidimensional object php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, object

I have this array of objects:

```
[{'id':1, 'name':'name1', 'src':'1'},
 {'id':1, 'name':'name1', 'src':'2'},  
 {'id':2, 'name':'name2', 'src':'1'},
 {'id':2, 'name':'name2', 'src':'2'}]
```

And i want to group them by the src in an array like so:

```
[{'id':1, 'name':'name1', 'src':['1','2']},
 {'id':2, 'name':'name2', 'src':['1','2']}]
```

Please help i am stuck on that for a good while now, sorry for the novice question.

Comment: Please share what you have tried. There are a lot of answers for this right here on SO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: all basic ways to sort arrays and data in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Comment: Looks more like JSON to me isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$array = [{'id':1, 'name':'name1', 'src':'1'},
    {'id':1, 'name':'name1', 'src':'2'},  
    {'id':2, 'name':'name2', 'src':'1'},
    {'id':2, 'name':'name2', 'src':'2'}];
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array as $data)
{
    if ( ! array_key_exists($data['id'], $new_array))
    {
        $new_array[$data['id']] = array('id' => $data['id'], 'name' => $data['name'], 'src' => array());
    }
    $new_array[$data['id']]['src'][] = $data['src'];
}
```

Comment: i got an error "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" so i changed all `$data[]` to `$data->` and it worked. thank you thank you!